# Retrieve SharePoint list in DataTable with Condition

Tags: list, caml-query, caml, datatable

** I have a Sharepoint List called "Resources" and have various Fields as shown below and same returns as DataTable:

```
ID    Title     Role       LoginName    Enable[Yes/No] 
1    Pranav    Developer    BW\PPB       Yes
2    Rohit     Tester       BW\RW        No
3    Sarang    Account      BW\SJ        No
4    Amit      Soft.Eng     BW\AI        Yes
4    Kunal     Soft.Eng     BW\KT        Yes
```

**My code:

```
 public static DataTable GetListData()
        {
            DataTable returnTable = null;

            SPSite thisSite = null;
            SPWeb thisWeb = null;
            SPList thisList = null;

            try
            {
                thisSite = new SPSite(siteLink);
                thisWeb = thisSite.OpenWeb();
                thisList = thisWeb.Lists["Resources"];
                if (thisList.Items.Count > 0)
                   {
                filterQuery = new SPQuery();
                filterQuery.ViewFields = PopulateFieldsParameter("Title,Role,AddtionalRoles,Designation,LoginName,ClientBillable,NonBillable, EnableChatting,LoggedIn,EnableTimesheet,DesignationTitle,pmPODEnable");
                returnTable = thisList.GetItems(filterQuery).GetDataTable();
                   }
            returnTable = thisList.Items.GetDataTable();
            }
             return returnTable;
         }
```

With this above code i am able to retrieve whole list data but i want to get table(rows) whose Enable is Yes.

**Actual Output**

```
   ID    Title     Role       LoginName    Enable[Yes/No] 
    1    Pranav    Developer    BW\PPB       Yes
    2    Rohit     Tester       BW\RW        No
    3    Sarang    Account      BW\SJ        No
    4    Amit      Soft.Eng     BW\AI        Yes
    5    Kunal     Soft.Eng     BW\KT        Yes
```

**Expected Output** -Condition= Enable == Yes

```
ID    Title     Role       LoginName    Enable[Yes/No] 

1    Pranav    Developer    BW\PPB       Yes
4    Amit      Soft.Eng     BW\AI        Yes
5    Kunal     Soft.Eng     BW\KT        Yes
```

Help..!!

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static DataTable GetListData()
    {
        DataTable returnTable = null;

        SPSite thisSite = null;
        SPWeb thisWeb = null;
        SPList thisList = null;

        try
        {
            thisSite = new SPSite(siteLink);
            thisWeb = thisSite.OpenWeb();
            thisList = thisWeb.Lists["Resources"];

            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            string camlquery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Enable' /><Value Type='Text'>" + true + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
            query.Query = camlquery;
            SPListItemCollection spcol = thisList.GetItems(query);  

            returnTable = spcol.GetDataTable();
        }
     }
```

Comment: verify caml query..

Comment: i have edited my code above...plz check it

Comment: where is your filter query to filer results based on Enable filds

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (thisList.Items.Count > 0)
                returnTable = thisList.Items.GetDataTable();
```

Use below code:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Enable\" /><Value Type=\"Boolean\">1</Value></Eq></Where>";
SPListItemCollection itemCol = list.GetItems(query);
var dataTbl = itemCol .GetDataTable();
```